# JPA/Hibernate. How to prevent inherit field get's class prefix automatically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Following situation: When i try to save an entity with an @EmbeddedId field, hibernate makes the field "mandant" from the base class to "contact_mandant" an throws an invalid identifier error. The column name in the table "Contact" is "mandant" and not "contact_mandat".
I just dont understand why it happens automatically that the fieldname is changed.
Here some code:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseId implements Serializable {

      @Column(name = "Mandant", precision = 2, nullable = false)
      protected Byte mandant;

      ...getter, setter...
    }

    @Embeddable
    public class ContactId extends BaseId implements Serializable {

       @Column(name = "Id_Contact", precision = 9)
       private Long id;

      ...getter, setter...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Contact extends Base {

      @EmbeddedId
      private ContactId contactId;

      ...getter, setter...
    }

   @Entity(name = "Employee")
   public class Employee extends Base {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    @MapsId("contactId")
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "Mandant"),
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "Id_Contact")
    })
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Contact contact;

       ...getter, setter...
    }

   @Embeddable
   public class EmployeeId extends BaseId implements Serializable {

     @Column(name = "Id_Employee", precision = 9)
     private Long id;

     private ContactId contactId;

      ...getter, setter...
    }
```

I'm coming from the .Net world and i'm not that much familiar with JPA yet. Could someone give me a friendly hint what i'm doing wrong or where the problem lies with my implementation, please?

Best regards
Newsman

P.s.: Spring 4 and Hibernate 5

Answer (score 0):

Solution with shared composite key:

Without "id" in @MapsId the framework generate following query:

"insert into EMPLOYEE_DETAILS (AEN_DATUM, SACHB_KZ, DETAILS, employee_id_employee, employee_MANDANT) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

After adding "id" to @MapsId the query is:

"insert into EMPLOYEE_DETAILS (AEN_DATUM, SACHB_KZ, DETAILS, id_employee, MANDANT) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends Base {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "SUR_NAME", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surName;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId extends BaseId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id_employee", precision = 9)
    private Long employeeId;
...
}

@Entity(name = "EmployeeDetails")
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS")
public class EmployeeDetails extends Base {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    @Column(name = "DETAILS", nullable = false)
    private String details;

    @MapsId("id")
    @OneToOne
    private Employee employee;
...
}
```

It's not the same implementation as above, but the problem was the same. The query was generate with CONTACT_MANDANT instead of MANDANT.

peace